How Beckhoff XTS Linear product transport system works
I'm an electrical engineer, I work in the industrial automation industry, I've experience with different kinds of electric motors (asynchronous, brushless, torque, linear...) and I think to understand how all of them works and their control algorithms a part from one specific case: Beckhoff's XTS Linear Product Transport System.
This system consists of a linear track (that can also form a closed loop) where multiple carts, especially to move small items from one are to another on the production line, can move back and forth .
The cool thing is that all the cart can move independently one from the others with different speeds, movement profile and can be also precisely positioned.
Here you can find a promotional video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rh8HfCHlyNc&ab_channel=BeckhoffAutomation
I don't understand how it is possible to have such freedom given that the carts are completely passive and the control is made by the track.
The system looks similar to a linear motor with the coils in the track but how are the arranged and controlled?
Can someone who knows better than me give me some?
Thank you
PS. I'm not affiliated with the manufacturer nor with one of their competitors, I'm just curious in how things works and I'd like to learn something new.

Dave - Welcome. (a) FYI please see the [tour] & [help] as Stack Exchange rules differ from typical forums. (b) This question has appeared to potentially be spam to a site member (e.g. potentially linking to something you're affiliated with and benefit from promoting). On the other hand, if this is a genuine question (as I think), and if you didn't link to what you were asking about, people would ask for more information - as the saying goes: "damned if you do, damned if you don't". Is there something you can add via an [edit], for those who may be suspicious of the question's motives? TY

(P.S. I'll leave it for community voting to decide whether this question should be considered on-topic here or not. I don't see it as definitely off-topic, but nor is it clearly on-topic.  If a site member does know how that specific system works then you might get an answer. However, we don't want uninformed speculation as that has no value for you or for future readers.)

SamGibson - Thank you for your kind reply. This question is not a spam, I'm genuinely interested into understand how this kind of works and I'm nowhere affiliated with the manufacturer nor I work for one of their competitors. I'm just curious and since I can't find any source on internet I decided to make a post here. I will edit the post to try to clarify.

Why do you think the Movers are passive with an optical communication bus and a power control bus?

https://download.beckhoff.com/download/document/motion/xts_software_en.pdf  & https://www.beckhoff.com/en-ca/products/motion/xts-linear-product-transport/at8x00-at9xxx-ath9xxx-xts-guide-rails-and-movers/at9014-x070-x550.html?

I mean that they are passive in the means of generating the driving magnetic field. Multiple linear motor have the coils on the mover not in the track and every mover has a power supply cable but this is not the case. I'd like to understand the logic behind the moving magnetic field that move every mover independently.

The documentation from that company says that the cars have strong magnets in them, they have an ID tag, and some of them also have a method of picking up power (for actuators etc, not basic motion).
To work, such a system needs to have lots of individually controlled coil segments, and obviously rather sophisticated computer control.
But the basic mechanism looks conceptually straightforward:


A linear track with "individually" switchable coil segments
Moving cars with fixed magnets, pushed along by just-right switching of the coils
An RFID system, so you know which car is where
A transformer system to provide power to the cars

The trick is of course to get everything working well, reliably, efficiently.
https://download.beckhoff.com/download/document/motion/xts_ba_en.pdf

This makes sense. Indeed having multiple small coil solves the problem of independent movers control. The control software must be really interesting. Thanks.
